# Sails.js, Waterline and Joins

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I'm having two models with a many-to-many association: User, Projects

In other words: Users belong to any number of projects and projects belong to any number of users.

Now I want to retrieve all projects which belong to a certain user id. How can I achieve this?

The following query returns ALL projects in my database with an array of `users` which has one property when the user is found, otherwhise it's empty.

```
Projects.find().populate('users',{id : my_user_id});
```

Project model

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name : {
      type : 'string',
      maxLength : 80,
      required : true
    },
    users : {
      collection : 'User',
      via : 'projects'
    },

  }
}
```

User model:

```
var User = {
  // Enforce model schema in the case of schemaless databases
  schema: true,

  attributes: {
    firstname  : {
      type: 'string',
      size : 60
    },
    lastname  : {
      type: 'string',
      size : 60
    },
    email     : {
      type: 'email',
      unique: true,
      required : true,
      size : 80

    },
    passports : {
      collection: 'Passport',
      via: 'user'
    },
    projects : {
      collection : 'Project',
      via : 'users'
    },
    toJSON: function() {
      var obj = this.toObject();
      delete obj.passports;
      delete obj.projects;
      return obj;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: You should post the relevant parts of your model definitions.

Answer (score 4):

You have to go the other way around... That is, to find the user first, and then populate the project associations like so:

```
User.findOne(userid)
    .populate('projects')
    .exec(function(err, projects) {
        // projects for that user returned
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

@Melvin's solution works great, but you can also do:

```
Project.find({users: [my_user_id, second_user_id]})
.populate('users')
.exec(function(err, projects) {

});
```